# Is the expression $E_n^0\langle\psi_n^0|\psi_n^2\rangle=E_n^2\langle\psi_n^0|\psi_n^2\rangle$ a valid expression?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra

Given the Hermitian operator $H^0$ and the two quantum states $\psi_n^0$ (ground-state) and $\psi_n^2$ (second permutation), we can exploit the Hermitivity of this operator to derive the following expression:

$$\langle\psi_n^0|H^0\psi_n^2\rangle=\langle H^0\psi_n^0|\psi_n^2 \rangle=E_n^0\langle\psi_n^0|\psi_n^2\rangle$$

Now, my question is the following: If we can use the Hermiticity of $H_0$ this way, would we then be allowed to write the following?:

$$\langle\psi_n^0|H^0\psi_n^2\rangle=\langle\psi_n^0|E_n^2\psi_n^2\rangle=E_n^2\langle\psi_n^0|\psi_n^2\rangle$$

So, as a result, we have:

$$E_n^0\langle\psi_n^0|\psi_n^2\rangle=E_n^2\langle\psi_n^0|\psi_n^2\rangle$$

and if so, how can we explain this physically?

Comment: Is $\psi_n^2$ an eigenstate of $H_0$? ;)

Comment: Obviously not; thank you for answering. -I completely overlooked that.

Comment: If $\psi_n^2$ must be an eigenstate of some operator, say $H_m$, we require that $m=2$. Can we than say anything about the operator $H_0$ operating on $\psi_n^2$? Is it undefined or is it zero? In the general case; if we apply an operator on a state that is not an eigenstate -what do we get?

Comment: In general the action of an operator on a state is a new state: typically a linear combination of energy eigenstates (or in general any basis).

Comment: Okay, thank you. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [QM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics), after quantization, Hamiltonian is a Hermitian(or [self-adjoint operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator)) operator. An important property of Hermitian operators is that if $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are two different eigenstates with eigenvalues $E_1$, $E_2$ of $H$

- if $E_1\ne E_2$, $(\psi_1,\psi_2)=0$.
- if $E_1= E_2$, one can find a set of new basis s.t. $(\psi_1^\prime,\psi_2^\prime)=0$, where $\psi_1^\prime=A_1\psi_1+B_1\psi_2$ and $\psi_2^\prime=A_2\psi_1+B_2\psi_2$.

You can find proof for this point in many basic textbooks about QM, and to my taste, I recommend [Modern Quantum Mechanics by  J. J. Sakurai and Jim Napolitano](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108473229).

**Thus for both two cases, if $\psi_0$ and $\psi_2$ are really two eigenstates of $H^0$ this equality is valid.**

**To your question, $\psi_2$ is not an eigenstate of $H^0$. In most cases, it is not an eigenstate for any operator in theory**. To see this point we write the time-independent perturbation equation
\begin{align}
\left(H^0+\sum_{l}\epsilon^lH^l\right)\left(\psi_n^0+\sum_{k}\epsilon^k\psi_n^k\right)=\left(E_n^0+\sum_{l}\epsilon^lE_n^l\right)\left(\psi_n^0+\sum_{k}\epsilon^k\psi_n^k\right)\, ,
\end{align}
To see this formula, you can see [Perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)). $\psi_2$ is nothing but a single term in the expansion of the exact eigenstate with respect to a small dimensionless characteristic parameter we consider at some order of your interest.

Comment: Thank you. Why is $\psi_2$ an eigenstate of $H^0+\epsilon H^1$? What does $H^1$ represent here? I understand that $\psi_2$ is the first excited state, so it makes sense that we have to add something to the ground state operator, but can you please clarify on the argument for this?

Comment: Perhaps perturbation implies that if we add the (first-order) perturbation, say $H_1$, multiplied by some constant, say $\epsilon$, to the exact solution then we get an $\textit{approximation}$ of the first excited state. Is this understood correctly?

Comment: @RasmusAndersen There are some confusions from my original answer, I have updated it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted in the comments, $\psi_n^2$ is not an eigenstate of the Hermitian ground-state operator $H^0$, so $H^0|\psi_n^2\rangle\neq E_n^2|\psi_n^2\rangle$.